# How to rewrite field with php in views?

Tags: 6, views

I need to do a string replacment with php on a title field in views 3 / drupal 6.So i would to know the best way because after research i found these:

- use Views PHP module
- use Computed fields module
- use PHP in the views template
- use a template file   like field.tpl.php (only for D7 ?)

Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you should never use [PHP in Views](https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2013/12/26/44497-people-are-wrong-how-to-never-use-views-php/). As the linked page mentions, you should write your own handler or plugin.